# Update registry key if equal to a value with VBS

Tags: vbscript, registry

i would like to update a registry key value if equal to "1" then Change it to "2"
If =2 then no action
with VBS
Example :

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software
VALUE1 = 1

[image: see picture below for Example :]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' read the valor

Val01=WshShell.RegRead ("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Value1")

' if valor = 1 then change 1 > 2

msgbox Val01

```
    if val01=1 then 

               WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Value1",2,  "REG_SZ"

    end if
```